# Is there a way to access nested python dictionaries in django template without template tag or database query?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

Without using a custom template tag or database queries - what would be the best way ...  or any way to display the following dict values in a template page without calling any key explicitly until getting to the final level (name, profession, fun fact):

```
upcoming_meetings = {

dateOne: {
    PersonOne:{
        Name:"valueOne",
        Profession:"valueTwo", 
        Fun_Fact:"valueThree"
    },
    PersonTwo:{
        Name:"valueOne",
        Profession:"valueTwo", 
        Fun_Fact:"valueThree"
    }
},
dateTwo: {
    PersonOne:{
        Name:"valueOne",
        Profession:"valueTwo", 
        Fun_Fact:"valueThree"
    },
    PersonTwo:{
        Name:"valueOne",
        Profession:"valueTwo", 
        Fun_Fact:"valueThree"
    }
}

}
```

I've gotten as far as trying the following combination but have only gotten as far as the "dates" level displaying in a formatted fashion and all other values displaying as unfiltered and unformatted dictionary values.

```
{% for date, person in upcoming_meetings.items %} 
    <h4>{{ date }}</h4>
    <p>{{ person }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% for date, persons in upcoming_meetings.items %} 
<h4>{{ date }}</h4>
<p>{{ persons.PersonOne }}</p>
<p>{{ persons.PersonTwo }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

You retrieve the value of each date, then access it the way you want. You can do `<p>{{ persons.PersonOne.Name }}</p>` and it will work.

**EDIT** After @ChefJulian comment saying that he don't want call each key explicitly, want to say that it wouldn't make sense to write that level of automation but if you insist, thats the answer.

```
{% for date, persons in upcoming_meetings.items %} 
<h4>{{ date }}</h4>
{% for k, v in persons.items %}
{% for k, v in v.items %}
<p>{{ k }} : {{ v }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

That will work for each date and each person related to it and each data related to the person.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. However, question explicitly give the following parameter: “ without calling any key explicitly until getting to the final level (name, profession, fun fact)”, in this scenario the names of the people would be constantly changing

Comment: @ChefJulian Edited The answer, mark it if it worked.